# Converting Assembly Code To Machine Code

Tags: assembly

My Question is How can I know the exchangeable machine code of the instructions of the assembly code?
And how to write a binary file that can be executed?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a piece of assembly code and want to execute it, you will first need to run it through an **assembler** to produce a binary. There are a number of assemblers available, I would recommend starting with [NASM](http://www.nasm.us/) since it's pretty popular and runs on several platforms.

Then, to assemble/link your program, just run:

```
nasm -o object.o your-source-file.asm
ld -s -o your-output-executable object.o
```

Answer (score 0):

What assembly language are you using? That will determine the program you use to compile the assembly code into machine code. If you post a snippet of your assembly code, someone may be able to identify it for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you Using Windows just do the next:
Go to Run and write cmd then write debug write a100 then
write any assembly instruction then press enter,
write r , then machine code of your assembly instruction will appear on the left side of the black Dos screen.
I hope it help some.

Answer (score -1):

Use cc -S file_name.c

It will populate you assembly code of your c program